# MimeKit to read compressed data

Tags: c#, .net, compression, mime, mimekit

Using MimeKit to read MimeMessage like so:

```
var message = MimeMessage.Load("C:\\test\\as2\\RawMIMEMsg.txt");
var part = message.BodyParts.FirstOrDefault();

var ms = new MemoryStream();
part.WriteTo(ms);
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test\\as2\\MIMEWrittenPart.txt", ms.ToArray());
```

Where RawMIMEMsg.txt looks like so:
[image]

I can't figure out how to get decompressed content out of `part` using MimeKit library. The only method I see is `WriteTo` but it basically writes this part as is to a file without decompressing it.

Comment: A Mime attachment starts two dashes on a new ling.  The attachments are in the body of the response.  The compression is GZIP and can be decompresses as shown here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream

Comment: try var part = message.BodyParts.FirstOrDefault() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime, then you'll see decompress method

Comment: @bgman Thanks! If you respond with this - I will mark as an answer. This is all I needed. Now I need to look at MimeKit code to understand how it's done :) Attempts to use GZIP directly all failed..

Comment: @jdweng Where do you get it that it is GZip compression? S/MIME normally uses CMS encryption and compression

Comment: @Charlieface What IS CMS compression? Can't find anything.. Is there built-in .NET wayt o handle it? Under the hood, MimeKit uses BouncyCastle for decompression...

Comment: I think you need something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.envelopedcms.decode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 although I've never used it before so don't know. If you are using MimeKit they should have a decoder/filter for it anyway

Comment: @Charlieface. No, don't use MimeKit, and, as I said - I looked through code and they themselves use BouncyCastle for decompression

Comment: @Charlieface : The header to the MIME data.  Nothing says that it is encrypted.  Why would you need encryption when the SMTP is already encrypted?

Comment: @jdweng And the header does not say GZip, it says it's S/MIME `pkcs7-mime` which is encrypted (and it's in a signed PKCS7 envelope), and it says it's also compressed, but it's using CMS envelope compression. Not every compression is GZip. SMTP might be encrypted (but doesn't have to be), but it does not guarantee encrypted delivery of the message to the receiver, only to the next server, nor does it prevent it being tampered on the way by a rogue server. It's not end-to-end encryption and signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
 if(message.BodyParts.FirstOrDefault() is ApplicationPkcs7Mime part && part.SecureMimeType==SecureMimeType.CompressedData)
{
    var mimeentity = part.Decompress();
    ...
}
```

The WriteTo method on the first part is useful to get the data for Mic calculation.