# Decompressing GZIP data inside Mime message. Found Invalid data while Decoding

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzip, bouncycastle

I need to decompress data inside MIME message. Data marked with `compressed-data`
Here is code I tried:

```
using (var msi = new MemoryStream(content))
using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    gs.CopyTo(mso);
    var a = mso.ToArray();
}
```

Getting exception:

> Found invalid data while encoding    at
> System.IO.Compression.InflaterZlib.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)    at
> System.IO.Compression.InflaterZlib.ReadInflateOutput(Byte[]
> outputBuffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32&
> bytesRead)    at System.IO.Compression.InflaterZlib.Inflate(Byte[]
> bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)    at
> System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] array,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
> at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)

I know it's GZIP in this block of data (per RFC). Ok, I asked question here
[MimeKit to read compressed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465126/mimekit-to-read-compressed-data?noredirect=1#comment129741182_73465126)

Got some pointers, after looking through MimeKit code, I found that they actually use BouncyCastle decompression under the hood. Specifically, I was able to make it work with following code. (same data sample):

```
var cdata = File.ReadAllBytes("C://test//as2//CompressedContentPartContent.bin");
CmsCompressedDataParser ed = new CmsCompressedDataParser(cdata);
var aa = CmsTestUtil.StreamToByteArray(ed.GetContent().ContentStream);
```

I try to avoid using 3rd party libs (company policy), and seems like it's standard GZIP, so I am confused why standard .NET library gives error.

Any suggestions onto why standard .NET `GZipStream` and `DeflateStream` give me error (same error)? What is different with `CmsCompressedDataParser` ?

I tried another 3rd party lib `SharpZipLib` on this data and it failed but with different error.

> Error GZIP header, first magic byte doesn't match at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream.ReadHeader() at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count) at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils.Copy(Stream source, Stream
> destination, Byte[] buffer) at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZip.Decompress(Stream inStream, Stream
> outStream, Boolean isStreamOwner)

I compared 2 such data structures and first bytes (headers) match.

[image]

Comment: CMS is standard SMIME encryption and compression. The RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551.html doesn't say anything about GZip, not sure why you thought it was

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, that starts making sense, I will dig into it. I was looking at this RFC (for AS2 version 1.2 with compression): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3274 And it points to GZIP, so I thought this is what it is

Comment: Please don't ever put screen shots in your questions. We can't copy, search, anything on those. Copy the text and put that directly in your questions.

Comment: As best as I can tell, there are no gzip or zlib streams in your images of hex data.

Comment: @MarkAdler I marked this Q as answered. I learned that it is no ZLIB, it's CMS Compressed content. And so far, I only found BouncyCastle being able to handle it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't known CmsCompressedDataParser, but c you image, i sure that are not gzip or deflater data. gzip must start with 0x8B 0x1F, deflater first byte low 4bit must 0x8 for example 0x78

u can try two option,
first, in java byte order is BE, in c# you need try byte order as BE too

second, deflater may work on no wrap mode, mean the magic flag (first 2 bytes)
and CRC data will not output, so i say that not gzip/deflater.

Comment: I just updated my Q with SharpZipLib test, which failed as well. So, I am not completely sure what is your suggestion? I know for a fact it WORKS (I mean file is good) with Bouncy Castle and their CMS Data parser. So, data is good. Now, the question is, what to do with it to make it work.  Per RFC it should be GZIP data inside MIME...

Comment: @katit how can i suggestion.. you just ask why that data can't decoder as gzip and deflater, i answer u, that not gzip or deflater. i mean, you must ask encode by what first..

Comment: `1f 8b`, not `8b 1f`. Also, _zlib_ data must start with a low nybble of 8. Raw deflate data is different, and can take many values.

Comment: @MarkAdler see https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/inflate.c#L665 you will see 0x8b1f, but 0x1F8B also right because byteorder BE mode. then about low 8, it not same you think, see https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/inflate.c#L685

Comment: You are pointing at my code. The gzip header is `1f`, then `8b`. When read as a two-byte little endian integer, that is `0x8b1f`. It is _not_ `0x8b 0x1f`, as you wrote it. As for the 8, deflated data is not the same as zlib-wrapped deflated data. Learn about the difference.